# Extract number out of string in XML response in Postman

Tags: xml, postman

I am trying to get a numeric value out of string response in Postman. Struggling how to make it.

Here's a string I get in response:

< text > Unable to retry completed order: 1785, must be: 1990 < /text >

I would like to extract number '1990' out of string and use this value as a value for local variable for GET request in the same GET request where I am getting this response text (in Tests tab in Postman).

How to make it? would have some examples, please? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have sorted it out using javascript regex possibility. If someone will be interested:

```
var str = jsonData.sbalance.text; // parameter 'text' from responseBody
matches = str.match(/\d+/g);
let i = 0;
let secondNumber = matches[1]; // in response text there were two numeric values, 
needed second one.
pm.environment.set("orderId", secondNumber++);
```